# Derivations of the algebra of differential forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-forms

It is well known that the interior product, the Lie derivative, and the De Rham differential are derivations of the algebra of differential forms. Does there exist other derivations of this algebra but with degree $\pm k$ for $k\notin\{0,1\}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no and it is described in this article: A. Frolicher, A. Nijenhuis, Theory of vector valued differential forms. Part I, Indagationes Math. 18 (1956), 338-359.

**Edit:** There is a mistake in what I wrote above: the answer is yes (as said in the introduction of the paper), there exist derivations of the algebra of differential forms in any degree, see also

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%B6licher%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket#Derivations_of_the_ring_of_forms

for a summary of the structure of such derivations.

Comment: I had a quick look at that paper but I couldn't find a clear statement of the result. Could you specify where exactly in the paper the result is stated?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I am sorry, there is a mistake in what I wrote above, there exist derivations of arbitrary degree (I just read the introduction).